# Dynamically generating an EditText on touch in android

Tags: android

I am working on adding text to a canvas.What I need to do is,when the user clicks on the screen an edit text is generated on the position the user clicks on.The user enters text and when he is done editing the text combines with the image bitmap in the canvas on the position the user touched the sccreen.I know how to get the position and add text .I am finding it difficult to generate the EditText,

Comment: is it compulsory to generate the EditText? instead you can ask the user for text in some dialogbox and write the provided text on the clicked position of the canvas using canvas.drawText() kind of method.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. A parallel iOS app is being developed and they have implemented an editText on touch. So I will have to also implement it the same way

Comment: do you want to place the editText exactly where user touched or somewhere in the screen?

Comment: yes I want it where the user touched the screen

Answer (score 0):

The EditText if an android widget and placing a android widget inside a canvas probably will not work i.e view's events etc working. As android widget is not a "canvas object". Placing a EditText on Top of a canvas will work but then you don't need the canvas at all. Placing an EditText object to a layout at a obsolete position cannot be done directly. You can only place the object at different positions and then increase the margins do the EditText will distance the anchor position on canvas.

The game engine can be recomended for the stuf like this and you can use game engine like andengine.